# Files not downloaded showing binay data in ASP.NET core web API

Tags: asp.net-core

Trying to download multiplefile as zip using System.io.compression from asp.net core web api. But i got binary error text. How can i fix this? below is my code
Error:
Error from backend. {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":200,"statusText":"OK","url":"http://localhost:4000/api/filegeneration/createfile/2023-02-08/1","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","
message":"Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:4000/api/filegeneration/createfile/2023-02-08/1",
"error":{"error":{},"text":"PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\u0000\u0000\b\u0000��HV�
u0010\u0001\u000b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0003\u0000\u0000\u0000\u001e\u0000\u0000\u0000
Fareshare_Qty_08.02.2023_0.txtz�{?\u0000\u0000\u0000��\u0003\u0000PK\u0001\u0002\u0014
\u0000\u0014\u0000\u0000\u0000\b\u0000��HV�\u0010\u0001\u000b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0003\u0000\u0000
\u0000\u001e\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000Fareshare_Qty_08.02.2023_0.txtPK\u0005
\u0006\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0001\u0000L\u0000\u0000\u0000G\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000"}}
Controller:

```
using (var outstream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(outstream,ZipArchiveMode.Create,true))
                    {
                        foreach (string filePath in files)
                          {
                              var filearcive = archive.CreateEntry(Path.GetFileName(filePath),CompressionLevel.Optimal);
                            using (var entrystream = filearcive.Open())
                            {
                                using (var fileCompressionStream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath)))
                                {
                                   await fileCompressionStream.CopyToAsync(entrystream);
                                }
                            }
                           }
                     }
                outstream.Position = 0;
                return File(outstream.ToArray(), "application/zip", "Fareshare.zip");
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for me. Please check it.

```
    public (string fileType, byte[] archiveData, string archiveName) DownloadFiles(string subDirectory)
    {
        var zipName = $"archive-{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd-HH_mm_ss")}.zip";

        List<FileInfo> files = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, subDirectory)).GetFiles().ToList();

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
            {
                files.ForEach(file =>
                {
                    var theFile = archive.CreateEntry(file.Name);
                    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(theFile.Open()))
                    {
                        streamWriter.Write(File.ReadAllText(file.FullName));
                    }

                });
            }

            return ("application/zip", memoryStream.ToArray(), zipName);
        }
```

**Test Result**

[image]

Comment: How have take _hostingEnvironment ?

Comment: @user3510330 this is just for get the full path.

Comment: @user3510330 https://gist.github.com/CoreProgramm/676676526d87a534d297640dbd37954f

Comment: @user3510330 If it works for you or not, pls let me know.

Comment: I used my path  Path.Combine("C:\\AllobotFiles\\ ) instead of IWebHostEnvironment. Showing same error message.Not worked for me.

Comment: @user3510330 You should use IWebHostEnvironment.

Comment: @user3510330 Because after the web application is published, it only has full permissions to the publication folder. The problem you are currently encountering seems to be related to permissions, as my test results, I am sure my code is correct.